# select with parameters from table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to fetch data with additional row values from a table.

The select statement should be fetching,

1. select * from the table
2. But the first column should be having a value - 'C001' for each row that we select.

The actual table is as below,

```
Title           value
-------------   -------
abc_ef_1_123    53.2
abc_ef_1_1      43.2
abc_ef_1_11     23.1
abc_ef_1_12     45.2
abc_ef_1_13     56.4
def_cef_3_23    98.1
def_cef_3_3     53.2
def_cef_3_12    43.2
def_cef_3_13    23.1
def_cef_3_123   45.2
```

expected result should be as below,

```
ID        Title           value
-------   -------------   -------
C001      abc_ef_1_123    53.2
C001      abc_ef_1_1      43.2
C001      abc_ef_1_11     23.1
C001      abc_ef_1_12     45.2
C001      abc_ef_1_13     56.4
C001      def_cef_3_23    98.1
C001      def_cef_3_3     53.2
C001      def_cef_3_12    43.2
C001      def_cef_3_13    23.1
C001      def_cef_3_123   45.2
```

Please assist.

Comment: I'm curious if you mean to assign the value `C001` to each row or if you intend to select only rows with an `ID` of `C001`...  Lukasz has answered the former -- for the latter, `SELECT * FROM [yourTable] WHERE @id=[yourTable].[id]` would get your result.

Answer (score 2):

As simple as:

```
SELECT 'C001' AS id, * FROM tab;
```